# How do I get the location of an XRControl like a label in Devexpress Reporting?

Tags: c#, devexpress, reporting, xtrareport

How do I get the location of an XRControl like a label in Devexpress Reporting so that I can detect two labels are not on the same page

I tried using the BeforePrint event but there the location is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try **AfterPrint**

```
   XRLabel label= new XRLabel();
   label.AfterPrint += (s, e) =>
   {
       var currentLocation = ((XRLabel)s).LocationF;
   };
```

Comment: My main problem is when a label is near the bottom of one page and its relevant content(table) is on the next page, I need to push the label on the next page.

Comment: Place XRLabel and the other content into `XRPanel` and do not forget to enable the XRPanel.KeepTogether property.